# Application no longer runs in release mode after updating to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015, upgrade

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2015 (and I still have VS 2012 on my machine).

I opened a solution in VS 2015 and after being prompt that is was incompatible I upgrading the solution and the upgrade log passed with flying colours (no issues).

However, although the solution builds and runs fine in debug mode, it does not work in release mode, it builds successfully but then crashes immediately when running the application.

The following exception message is shown:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

And here is a more descriptive image:

[image]

As can be seen, `"there is no code to show"`.

I am at a bit of a loss what to look for here to find what the problem is. I have done plenty of searching but seems to be a lot of similar issues, but not this particular one.

So, how do I fix this issue? Or at least what can I do to further investigate the problem and find a solution?

Comment: Is there anything of use in the callstack, or is all of that external code too?

Comment: The exception assistant got useless in VS2015 to debug static constructor crashes that occur very early.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General and tick "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".  If that still doesn't help, it should, then you'll have to divine it from the debugger's Call Stack window.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Call stack just says `[External Code]`

Comment: Enable unmanaged debugging, look in the Output window.

Comment: @HansPassant: Just enabled that, and although I get the same problem, I do now get an additional "View Detail" link in the actions. This is giving me something a bit more useful so I will investigate and come back with my findings

Comment: @HansPassant: I think your suggestion should be the answer. The error details I now have are specifically related to my code (it's a call to `System.IO.Path.Combine()` by the way) and I can debug that and solve it myself.

Comment: Don't hesitate to tell us about what you found in your own post, you know a lot more about it than I do.

Comment: @HansPassant: Do you know of any reason I should re-disable this setting after finishing with it? My instinct is to leave it enabled to avoid these issue in the future, but I wouldn't want to introduce others by leaving it on and forgetting I did it

Comment: I personally greatly prefer this setting, fighting bugs in the debugger is no joy and VS2015 has rather a lot of them.  You'll lose out on some stuff like E+C in x64 and return value debugging.  Meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Hans Passant in the comments, more information on the exception can be found by enabling the **Use Managed Compatibility Mode** option under:

Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Use Managed Compatibility Mode

[image]

Once enabled, when the application is restarted and the exception is thrown, there is an additional "Actions" option for "View Detail". As you can see from the screenshot in the question, this option was not previously available.

[image]

This provides a more detailed stack trace where I was able to identify the exact line of code that was causing the exception. I was then able to identify the cause and resolve my specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, since it was resolved, you could mark it as the answer later. Have a nice day:)